# What is an Image Gradient?

Tags: image, image-processing, gradient

I am currently, learning the working of **Seam Carving** aka *Content Aware Resizing*.

Seam Carving involves calculation of **Energy** of Each individual pixel in an image. Where the Energy could be calculated using several methods, one of which being **Gradient Magnitude** (Image Gradient).

I have previously used **Sobel Filter/Operator**, which involves calculation of gradients in *X* and *Y* direction, where the output of the two is used for finding edges. But, I am not quite sure what a **Gradient** is by definition.

**P.S.:-** I read the Wikipedia page of [Image Gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient) but was unable to understand it, clearly.

Comment: Imagine a *"relief map"* or topographical map of the landscape where sea-level is black in your image and mountain-tops are white. The gradient is just telling you how steep the ground is at any location and the direction tells you which way it goes up.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Nice Analogy!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Sobel you have computed the *derivatives* in the x and y directions.

These two derivatives together form the *gradient*. That is, the gradient has two values (a 2D vector) at each pixel. Because we have a vector at each pixel, we have a *vector field*.

The gradient gives the strength and the direction of the slope at each point. The magnitude of the gradient gives the slope strength.

Comment: for what are the magnitude, slope strength and direction used for?

Comment: @Vasu: they are used for many different things. The magnitude gives location and contrast of edges, the direction gives the orientation and polarity (light to dark or dark to light) of the edges.